# Use !important or specify more?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've got a general styling for a column specific to a unique "main" page on my site:

```
#main div.col50 {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Later in the same file, I need to override it because the element has a unique requirement from the designer: "it needs to be a little to the left":

```
#design-div {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Now, this doesn't override the first styling because it's a less-specific selector.  Is it better to:

- Use !important in the second style, but I don't want to be [this guy](http://oli.jp/img/2011/important-inheritance.png)
- Increase the selectivity (e.g. `#main #design-div`), even though it's an id (unique) and doing so violates [CSSLint rules](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-IDs-in-selectors) and smacks of [the beginning of a downward spiral into specificity](http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/)

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid using !important unless it is absolutely necessary. It makes code difficult to maintain because it stops the cascading working and so you can't rely on styles you set further down over-riding ones further up.

In your case you should do it like this:

```
#main #design-div.col50 {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

or take @JimmyRare's advice and use classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using id's in css, they have no purpose there. You can solve this issue by designing your css like this:

```
.main .col50 {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    width: 50%;
}

    .main .col50 .design-div {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
```

If you at some point feel like you have used `padding-left` a lot, you could turn it into a helper class instead.

```
.padding-left-none {
    padding-left: none !important;
}
```

Helper classes are the only place where I would recommend using `!important`, because it is intentionally set to override a default style.

Comment: "they have no purpose there" except to uniquely identify an element which has an exception to a layout, right?  It's not a class of thing that needs to be reused, but an individual that needs to be identified...

Comment: I have never experienced a situation where I would rather use ID, even if it's unique. You never know when the project expands and you want to reuse the class.